# AtttributeError with `vocab` in Migratation from Gensim 3 to 4 for NLP

Tags: python, nlp, gensim

I have the following problem to migrate Gensim 3 to 4.
The code is:

```py
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from matplotlib import pyplot
import numpy as np
# define training data
sentences = [['this', 'is', 'the', 'first', 'sentence', 'for', 'word2vec'],
            ['this', 'is', 'the', 'second', 'sentence'],
            ['yet', 'another', 'sentence'],
            ['one', 'more', 'sentence'],
            ['and', 'the', 'final', 'sentence']]
# train model
model = Word2Vec(sentences, min_count=1)
# fit a 2d PCA model to the vectors
X = model[model.wv.vocab]
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
result = pca.fit_transform(X)
# create a scatter plot of the projection
pyplot.scatter(result[:, 0], result[:, 1])
words = list(model.wv.vocab)
for i, word in enumerate(words):
    pyplot.annotate(word, xy=(result[i, 0], result[i, 1]))
pyplot.show()
```

The error is:

```
    ---> 14 X = model[model.wv.vocab]
```

The result of this code must be:
[pyplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bGA1.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you search Google for `[migrate Gensim 3 to 4]`, the top result should be the project's help wiki page, "[Migrating from Gensim 3.x to 4](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Migrating-from-Gensim-3.x-to-4)".

The [4th item](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Migrating-from-Gensim-3.x-to-4#4-vocab-dict-became-key_to_index-for-looking-up-a-keys-integer-index-or-get_vecattr-and-set_vecattr-for-other-per-key-attributes) on that page points out that the `vocab` attribute has changed, with examples of how to update older code that will no longer work (commented with ) into working code (commented with ):

> ##### 4. `vocab` dict became `key_to_index` for looking up a key's integer index, or `get_vecattr()` and `set_vecattr()` for other per-key attributes:
>
> ```py
> rock_idx = model.wv.vocab["rock"].index  #    
> rock_cnt = model.wv.vocab["rock"].count  # 
> vocab_len = len(model.wv.vocab)  # 
>
> rock_idx = model.wv.key_to_index["rock"]
> rock_cnt = model.wv.get_vecattr("rock", "count")  # 
> vocab_len = len(model.wv)  #
> ```

Your code only uses `model.wv.vocab` as a way to get a sequence or list of the model's known words, so you could just replace all instances of `model.wv.vocab` with `model.wv.key_to_index`, which just like the old `.vocab` is a `dict` with all known words as keys. EG:

```
X = model[model.wv.index_to_key]
```

...and later also...

```
words = list(model.wv.index_to_key)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```py
    ...
    X = model.wv[model.wv.key_to_index]
    ...
    words = list(model.wv.index_to_key)
    ...
```

<sub>Note: Solution provided by OP on question section.</sub>